# ref.push().key & ref.child (Type mismatch)

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a problem in this tutorial...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I485b7LzYkM

There are three items. An editText, a ratingBar, and a button. When you click on the button the rating is sent to the database. But I'm having issues with "heroId." Under ref.child(heroId) I get the error "Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected" for heroId. Any ideas?

Here is the code below:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var editTextName: EditText
    lateinit var ratingBar: RatingBar
    lateinit var buttonSave: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        editTextName = findViewById(R.id.editTextName)
        ratingBar = findViewById(R.id.ratingBar)
        buttonSave = findViewById(R.id.ratingBar)

        buttonSave.setOnClickListener {
            saveHero()
        }
    }

    private fun saveHero() {
        val name = editTextName.text.toString().trim()

        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            editTextName.error = "Please enter a name"
            return
        }

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("heroes")
        val heroId = ref.push().key

        val hero = Hero(heroId, name, ratingBar.numStars)

        ref.child(heroId).setValue(hero).addOnCanceledListener {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Hero saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }


    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921767/type-mismatch-inferred-type-is-string-but-string-was-expected), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62197209/why-do-i-get-this-kotlin-type-mismatch-inferred-type-is-string-but-string-wa), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080210/kotlin-type-mismatch-inferred-type-is-string-but-string-companion-was-expected), and many others on the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `val heroId = ref.push().key` snippet uses the [`DatabaseReference.getKey()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#getKey()), which returns a `String?` - so an optional string.

The [`DatabaseReference.child()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#child(kotlin.String)) requires a `String` - so a non-optional string.

So you'll need to ensure the optional string really has a value. Since you generate it client-side, that is guaranteed by the code already, so you can hard-cast it:

```
val heroId = ref.push().key!!
```

To learn all about dealing with these optional types and null-safety, I recommend spending some time in the Kotlin documentation on [null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).